# Use Ipython Notebook to produce reports

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use Ipython Notebook as a tool to share my research findings. I would like to output the notebook as a report in html or pdf format. The thing is I just want the report to include the markdown text and the code output (some charts and tables), and have the code hidden. How can I do this?

I did some online research, and tried adding a code block which reads:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 $('div.input').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.input').show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code."></form>''')
```

it does create a button which toggles on/off the raw code, but if I download the notebook as an html file and share it with others, the reader could still use the button to see the code.

Is there a better way to just share the result, and hide the raw code?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can only answer part of your question, I haven't tested how the pdf output would work.

But for HTML, I have tried below solution and it worked.

In the notebook, put a cell with code like below:

```
#Apply styles
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def css_styling():
    styles = open("styles/custom.css", "r").read()
    return HTML(styles)
css_styling()
```

And then in the style folder, create custom.css, which contains towards the end:

```
div.input_area { display:none;}
```

Then output the notebook as html.

Please let me know if the result works.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'styles/custom.css'